# Synchronously assign get request body to variable - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Future function which uses a get request and I save the request body to a variable {**data**}. It works well, however when I run my application and try loading a page with the data the variable is accessed before being assigned the value. It is only after I hot reload that it shows.

How do I make the whole page wait until the variable is assigned?

```
 static Future<Ticket> futureTicket;

 Map<String, dynamic> data;

 Future<Ticket> fetchTicket() async {
 final response =
    await http.get('http://hostname/getRequest');

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
      this.data = json.decode(response.body);

     //print("Data Here: " + data.toString());
      return Ticket.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); 
     } else {

    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Ticket');
    }

   }

   @override
     void initState(){
     futureTicket = fetchTicket();
     super.initState();
   }
```

---

Comment: use `FutureBuilder` luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a FutureBuilder widget, it takes a future mathed

```
Future<Ticket> fetchTicket() async {
 final response =
    await http.get('http://hostname/getRequest');

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
      this.data = json.decode(response.body);

     //print("Data Here: " + data.toString());
      return Ticket.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); 
     } else {

    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Ticket');
    }

   }

     FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchTicket()(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // this means the fetching is completed 
            var data = snapshot.data;
            /// you can do what ever you like with [data] variable
            return YourWidget();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            // this means incomplete get Request
            return YourErrorWidget()
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
```

Comment: you should not use `future: yourGetRequest**()**` - for more read official `FutureBuilder` documentation

Comment: in this case the yourGetRequest() method must return a type , so thats kind of obvious,

Comment: what type? you cannot use a function that returns `Future` that way

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html - read the second paragraph, starting from *"The future must have been ..."*